# Mysql: ST_Contains with borders to detect if multipolygon contains point

Tags: mysql, spatial, spatial-query, point-in-polygon, mysql-spatial

I use mysql spatial functions.

I have to understand if points lies withing multipolygon.
Initially I used `MBRContains` but it works in a strange way, so I faced the following error: [Mysql function MBRContains is not accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39582184/2674303)

[image]

My next step was switching to the functions `ST_Contains`. But I found out that if I use polygon(from multipolygon) vertex as argument - function returns false but I want to unclude all multipolygon borders.

### P.S.

I found that where are function:

> ST_Touches(g1, g2)
>
> Two geometries spatially touch if their interiors do not intersect,
>   but the boundary of one of the geometries intersects either the
>   boundary or the interior of the other

Looks like it works like I want(in `OR` conditions with `ST_contains`) but documentation is not clear for me. Can you explain how can 2 conditions be truth together
1. Interiors do not intersects
2. Boundary intersects the interrior.

?

### Question:

How can I achieve the behaviour I want?

Comment: What exactly is your question again. What does the data look like?

Comment: @Salman A, I am sorry, I can't add more information. Could you please specify your question?

Comment: I mean I cannot feed the picture to MySQL. What exactly does the data look like?

Comment: @Salman A, According NDA I can't provide concrete data. But you can create polygon similar to the picture

Comment: So you have a polygon and a point and you want to check if point is present/not inside polygon?

Comment: @Salmam, yes, I want check if point locates inside polygon. If point locates on a polygon border, then answer must be true

Comment: The interiors cannot intersect and interior touches boundary are both true if and only if the polygons are **touching**. That's why the function is called ST_Touches. I don't know why @gstackoverflow's answer is not correct for your case, seems to work no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a working solution:

```
ST_Contains(g1,g2) || ST_Touches(g1, g2)
```

Comment: It solved my question. Why do you think it is false positive ?

Comment: It may have been my data!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like  `ST_Distance(AREA, @point)) = 0` includes border